# How do I count the amount of reactions made on a specific emoji from a message that was sent? | discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot where a user makes a poll and if a certain emoji that the bot has reacted with reaches a number, say 10, then it does other actions. However, that is not my issue. My issue is collecting the amount of reactions itself from that emoji.

My Code:

```
    const embedSend = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [suggestionEmbed] }).then(async sEmbed => {
        await sEmbed.react('⬆️');
        await sEmbed.react('⬇️');
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['⬆️', '⬇️'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        sEmbed.awaitReactions({ filter, max: 20, time: 50000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            const reaction = collected.first();
            if (reaction.emoji.name === '⬆️') {
                console.log('up');
            } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '⬇️') {
                console.log('down');

            }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
           console.log("didnt reach 20 reacts");
        });
    });
```

I tried using the previous method above. However, it doesn't seem to actually print up or down for every reaction after reaching 20 reacts but instead it prints nothing or just `up` or just `down`. I've tried using the line of code below to count the emojis but no luck either:

```
  console.log(sEmbed.reactions.find(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === '⬆️').count)
```

Placed this inside of the `.then` statement with the `awaitReactions` right under the `If-else` block of code and got no output.

```
 embedSend.reactions.cache.get('⬆️').count;
```

This I've placed after the `embedSend` and it returns me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reactions' of undefined
```

and if i place it within the block of code tiehr the `embedSend` or `awaitReactions` and change it to `sEmbed` it returns nothing.

Comment: You're collecting max 20 reactions on a message, now you want to count how many reactions were '⬆️' and how many were '⬇️' from that 20 reactions right?

Comment: Exactly, I've been trying to do that for a while